# How to find when $f(x)>h(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I got two functions

- $f(x) = 3x+x(x+1) + 610$
- $h(x) = 817 + x$

How to calculate when $f(x) > h(x)$

In this case the answer is $x > 12$, but how do I calculate this?

I been trying to compare the f(x) to h(x) and find when they are equal, if I got an integer number than my answer is that integer -1, but if its not integer then I need to round it. I don't know how to put this in tow general solution.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? Add that to your question.

Comment: Do you want a positive integer solution or a real solution? In the first case $x>12$ is correct, in the second no!

Comment: Hint: Can you see when is the difference positive?

Comment: @mlainz Ok, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments and other answers you have to solve the inequality:
$$
x^2+3x-207>0
$$

The roots of the corresponding equations are:

$$
x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{837}}{2}
$$

so,  the solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ are the values $x< \dfrac{-3-\sqrt{837}}{2} \sim -15.97 $ or $x> \dfrac{-3+\sqrt{837}}{2} \sim 12.97$ .

If you want only integer solutions than you have $x>12$ or $x<-15$.

Answer (score 1):

First insert the expressions for f(x) and h(x) into the inequality:

$$3x+x(x+1)+610>817+x$$

Rearrange terms, all to right side:

$$x^2+3x-207>0$$

This is a parabola with two zeros, sketch the parabola and see where it has positive values. The zeros are important, because they will indicate a sign change.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2+3x+610\\h(x)=x+817$

Note that $f(0)<h(0)$ and so is for other values of $x$ but $x^2$ being of greater order than $x$, it is clear that $f(x)>h(x)$ for $x\notin I$ where $I$ is some interval.

One has $$f(x)=x^2+3x-207+h(x)$$ hence $f(x)>h(x)$ when the trinomial $x^2+3x-207$ is positive.

The roots of $x^2+3x-207=0$ are $x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-3\mp 3\sqrt{93}}{2}$ and the interval above is $I=[x_1,x_2]\approx [-15.9654,12.9654]$. Out of $I$ one has $f(x)>h(x)$.